# Adding field to work item in TFS results in permission error

Tags: tfs, scrum, azure-devops

In TFS I have a started a Scrum project, but I want to add some fields to a Work Item.

So I'm following [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2013/04/18/adding-completed-work-to-the-scrum-2-x-template-including-reporting.aspx) on how to add *Estimate* and *Completed* work hour fields to a Work Item.

I added one field in the layout, like shown in the tutorial. But when I try to save it I then get the following error:

```
TF237113: You don't have enough permissions to complete the import operation.
```

I think I have all the needed permissions. I changed all my user permissions and also the permissions I have in the TFS project that I'm working on.

[image]

But so far no luck. Even when I try to add a field in the `Layout` tab that already exists, then it still gives me that error. Anyone any idea what I can try to solve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using Visual Studio Online (Since I can see that you have a Windows Live ID), Visual Studio Online doesn't support process template customization at all at the moment. This is due to the fact that they release new versions of the service every 3 weeks or so, and having to consolidate and test all customization across all projects would be a major pain.

Comment: Just to make sure, so that I get what you mean. -- I'm using `visualstudio.com` which is the same as `Visual Studio Online`? Another thing, I'm using `visualstudio.com` to set the permissions of my user, but I'm using `VS2012` to add the new fields. So you're saying that this all goes through Visual Studio Online and thus it's not possible (at the moment) to customize templates?

Comment: Yes, visualstudio.com == Visual Studio Online and used to be called Team Foundation Service. Since the process is configured in the server, the server must support customization. Visual Studio Online currently does not permit you to make any customization to the process template.

There is an open Uservoice Ticket you can track to be informed on any changes to this situation: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3654231-customize-process-template-on-visual-studio-online

Comment: I see, to bad they don't support it yet. But thanks for answering!